# Widevine DRM and Android videoplayback issue

Tags: android, media-player, drm

I am facing a really annoying problem with the Widevine Library for Android. For some reason when trying to stream HLS with Widevine some devices (specially Samsung devices) give the following error when trying to play:

WV_Info_GetCodecConfig ESDS returned error 2002

After this, as it does not starts playing I stop, reset and release the media player as well as the DrmClient.

```
@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mPlayIndicator.setEnabled(false);
        mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mTimelineSeekBar.setMax(0);

        if (PlayerEnvConfig.USE_DEBUG_LOGGING) {
            Log.d("VideoPlayer", "ClosingVideoThread");
        }

        hideLoading();

        if (mScheduleTaskExecutor != null) {
            mScheduleTaskExecutor.shutdown();
        }

        if (mp != null) {

            if (PlayerEnvConfig.USE_DEBUG_LOGGING) {
                Log.d("VideoPlayer", "Stop Playing");
            }

            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop(); // It's always safe to call stop()
            }

            if (PlayerEnvConfig.USE_DEBUG_LOGGING) {
                Log.d("VideoPlayer", "Reset");
            }

            mp.reset();

            if (PlayerEnvConfig.USE_DEBUG_LOGGING) {
                Log.d("VideoPlayer", "Release");
            }

            mp.release(); // release resources internal to the MediaPlayer

            mMediaPlayer = null; // remove reference to MediaPlayer to allow GC
        }

        // IMPORTANT: It is important to release the DRM client after releasing the media player other wise there are
        // situations where the media player it is left in a bad state and does not play any more DRM protected content
        // until the restart of the device.

        // If the video is DRM protected then release the resource associated with the DRM.
        if (mIsDrmProtected) {
            mDrmManager.releaseDrmClient();
        }

        if (!mStopEventFired) {
            // Fire the event into the bus to the subscribed views to replace the views accordingly
            fireStopVideoPlaybackEvent();
        }
    }
```

And the code in the DrmManager to release the DrmClient:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void releaseDrmClient() {
    BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);

    if (mDrmManagerClient != null) {

        if (PlayerEnvConfig.USE_DEBUG_LOGGING) {
            Log.d("DRMManager", "Releasing DRM");
        }

        mDrmManagerClient.removeAllRights();

        // Starting from API 16 they included this function to release the drm client.
        int currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentApiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            mDrmManagerClient.release();
        }

        // Set to null so will be removed by the garbage collector
        mDrmManagerClient = null;

        if (PlayerEnvConfig.USE_DEBUG_LOGGING) {
            Log.d("DRMManager", "Releasing DRM Finally");
        }
    }
}
```

Ok well it does not play. I can confirm that all this code it is executed as they appear in the logs. BUT here is the really big problem, after this situation a process is left in the background (I cannot manage to find anywhere in the device which is the process) as if the video was still being played and the following error is shown constantly in the logs.

WVSession::SetWarning: status=2014, desc=MPEG2-TS continuity counter error

I realised because fir-stable the device gets really hot and second-able a used wireshark to sniff the traffic and I can see the requests made in the background.

This only happens when using HLS and Widevine, and when this last one fails playing. (The rights are actually retrieved and installed correctly but when trying to play fails).

Does anyone have any clue why this could be happening and specially how to avoid it??

Btw: The media player is embedded in a fragment, and this fragment inside another fragment.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use replacing http:// with widevine:// in video URI or not? 
This cause problems on some devices with ICS

Comment: Yeap. I replaced http:// with widevine://. I will try without it and let you know thanks.

Comment: After trying it it didnt help at all. :(